# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tfx.utils.dsl_utils'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-extended

I did install tfx version 1.2.1
Python: 3.8.2
Tensorflow: 2.5.2
pip: 21.3.1
I use window and installed the package through pip.

The error occurred when I did:

```
import os
from tfx.components import CsvExampleGen
from tfx.utils.dsl_utils import external_input
base_dir = os.getcwd()
data_dir = os.path.join(os.pardir, "data")
examples = external_input(os.path.join(base_dir, data_dir))
example_gen = CsvExampleGen(input=examples)
context.run(example_gen)
```

The error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14604/719215164.py in <module>
      1 import os
      2 from tfx.components import CsvExampleGen
----> 3 from tfx.utils.dsl_utils import external_input
      4 base_dir = os.getcwd()
      5 data_dir = os.path.join(os.pardir, "data")

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tfx.utils.dsl_utils'
```

I did full installation of tfx in which all packages are compatible. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: tfx.utils.dsl_utils isn't supported anymore. we have to from tfx.utils.dsl_utils import external_input, and use it to pass the external data_dir to CsvExampleGen. However, this does not work anymore. It would be nice to update this. Currently, TFX suggest passing the data_dir directly as a string. Even though this does not raise an error, it fails to ingest the .csv file. For more information please refer this colab [Gist](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tfx/blob/master/docs/tutorials/tfx/components_keras.ipynb)

Comment: So that means instead of using  external_input we use urllib.request.urlretrieve. How about CSV file or internal file, which syntax do we use instead?

Answer (score 4):

Just do the below:

```
# Example 1
context= InteractiveContext()
from tfx.components import CsvExampleGen
example_gen = CsvExampleGen(input_base='data')
context.run(example_gen)
```

data is the folder that you would have downloaded from the author's github. Just specify the folder name directly (or the path to the data folder).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
example_gen = CsvExampleGen(input_base=_data_root)
context.run(example_gen)
```

and change the Train to Split-train
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using 'external_input', send data_dir directly into the CsvExampleGen.

```
import os
from tfx.components import CsvExampleGen
base_dir = os.getcwd()
data_dir = os.path.join(os.pardir, "data")
example_gen = CsvExampleGen(input_base='data_dir')
```

This has worked for me. Looks like in tfx version 1._ , the module tfx.utils.dsl_utils doesn't exist.